# AWS Cloudfront allow access only if user's browser allows caching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to lower bandwidth charges. Is it possible to allow access to cloudfront only if a user's browser allows caching? I'm looking into a virtual private cloud but I don't see it working with cloudfront.

Comment: Check these [clever ideas](http://podlipensky.com/2012/02/how-to-check-if-browser-caching-disabled/) on detecting whether a browser is caching content or not.

Answer (score -1):

Amazon CloudFront does not require a user's browser to support caching.

Files are cached within CloudFront's edge locations (50+ worldwide). If a user requests information from a CloudFront distribution, their DNS lookup redirects to the closest edge location. If the edge location cache contains the data, it is returned to the user. If not, then the data is fetched from the Origin (eg Amazon S3, or a web server). The user's browser cache is not involved in this process.

Comment: Yes understood. I am trying to limit bandwidth expense by maximizing client side caching in the browser.